# How to add angular material to my seed web application

Tags: angular, angular-material, seedstack

I use seedstack in my web application , I want to know if there is a way to add angular-material.

NB : I use pom.xml to configure my dependancies, I also use seed 16.7.4 version, and angular 1.4.14 version.

I ried to add, the bellow dependancy to my pom :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
<artifactId>w20-bridge-web-material-theme</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I got this error when I tried access to the application :

```
[ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/ng/areq?  p0=w20MaterialCultureMenuController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Please find bellow my web dependancies, that I use :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
        <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-business-theme</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.i18n</groupId>
        <artifactId>i18n-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
        <artifactId>w20-bridge-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
        <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-dataviz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
        <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-bootstrap-3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.w20</groupId>
        <artifactId>w20-bridge-web-business-theme</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you depending only on the w20 theme that you want use ?

Are you calling `MenuService.registerActionType` or `MenuService.addAction` ?

Comment: I am not sure that I really understand what you mean by your question. But, I can say yes, I use only w20 theme for front-end dependancies (bootstrap, angular ...).
- For MenuService.registerActionType or MenuService.addAction : I am not using this methods.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix multiple CSS framework implementations or multiples themes in the same W20 application:

- The `w20-bridge-web-material-theme` dependency relies on `w20-bridge-web-material` dependency.
- The `w20-bridge-web-business-theme` dependency relies on `w20-bridge-web-bootstrap-3` dependency.

You have to choose either one but cannot have both in the classpath.